# How to download bcp utility for new OLE DB Driver for SQL Server (MSOLEDBSQL) without ODBC driver

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I'm using the new OLE DB Driver for SQL Server (MSOLEDBSQL) but am not using nor have the ODBC SQL Server driver. I need to use the bcp utility which is included in the "Microsoft® Command Line Utilities 14.0 for SQL Server" download. This however requires the ODBC SQL Server driver.

How may the bcp utility be installed without having to install the ODBC SQL Server driver?

Comment: BCP specifically requires the ODBC drivers, you need to install them; as per the system requirements in the documentarion: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-2017#download-the-latest-version-of-bcp-utility

Comment: OK, I see, but I wonder WHY it's required considering that MSOLEDBSQL is recommended to be used instead.

Comment: You'd need to talk to Microsoft about that; they are the one's that design the tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current BCP utility uses ODBC so you need to have the requisite ODBC driver installed.
Microsoft chose to use ODBC newer BCP versions presumably because ODBC is a better fit for cross-platform applications. OLE DB (MSOLEDBSQL driver) is a Windows technology.

MSOLEDBSQL is generally recommended when one uses OLE DB for SQL Server access because it's the newest OLE DB driver technology.

Comment: So even though I'm using bcp on Windows with the recommended MSOLEDBSQL driver, I'm still required to download and install the ODBC driver in order to use it. Good to know, but this is odd. Why would they recommend MSOLEDBSQL when ODBC will suffice. Confusing.

Comment: Not sure what you mean about bcp using the MSOLEDBSQL driver on Windows. AFAIK, bcp uses ODBC on Windows too.

Comment: bcp did not require odbc previously and I was able to use it with the old oledb driver. Now however, even though I'm using the new oledb driver, it also requires the odbc driver, which is strange. Microsoft should allow the bcp utility to be used without requiring the odbc driver.